# Why no cut-vertices or cut edges in a graph where eccentricity is same for all vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, proof-writing

I need help to prove the following statement.

There are no cut-vertices or cut-edges(bridges) in a graph where eccentricity is same for all vertices. I am getting that if the graph contains a cut-edge, then the eccentricity of end vertices of the bridge may contradict the fact that all vertices have same eccentricity. How to prove it theoretically. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a cut-edge if the eccentricity of each vertex is $1$: `o---o`.

Let $e>1$ be the common eccentricity of the vertices of $G$, and suppose that $\{u,v\}$ is a cut-edge. Let $w$ be a vertex of $G$ such that $d(u,w)=e$. Let $G'$ be the graph that remains when the edge $\{u,v\}$ is removed. If $w$ is in the same component of $G'$ as $u$, then any path from $v$ to $w$ must pass through $u$, and $d(v,w)=1+d(u,w)=1+e$, contradicting the hypothesis that the eccentricity of $v$ is $e$. Thus, $w$ is in the same component of $G'$ as $v$, and $d(v,w)=d(u,w)-1=e-1$. Similarly, if $z$ is a vertex such that $d(v,z)=e$, then $z$ is in the same component of $G'$ as $u$, and $d(u,z)=e-1$. What does this tell you about $d(w,z)$?